# Magnets in Transformers Design

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, magnetics

What is the advantages, and disadvantages of using neodymium magnets instead of ferrite cores in transformers?  How would the magnetic flux density vary of such a transformer utilizing a neodymium core?

Comment: Can you think of any advantage of using a magnet in a transformer core? It would bias the core and distort the output waveform, probably introducing even harmonics into the waveform.

Comment: Not to mention a intense magnetic pulse would weaken the magnets. Also neodymium cores loose ALL their magnetic field above 180 deg F. I have only seen the combination of a magnet and a coil in speakers, microphones and some latching relays.

Comment: In a transformer it is pointless (due to what has been mentioned), but in a DC choke, in addition to a magnetic material... they are quite good

Comment: not to mention the permeability of neodymium is comparable to AIR, while ferrites are closer to 5000x larger. Guess what is good in a magnetic circuit

Comment: @Sparky256, you can get neo grades that are good up to 200 C ... and even then, it depends on the magnetic circuit it is in.

Comment: @Eric. Ok. Thats good to know. I was referring to the first generation of NIB super-magnets with about 10,000 gauss. That was 10 years ago. There strength (pull) is scary strong, about 60 pounds sq inch. They can only get better. They will be a fundamental part of electric cars one fine day...

Comment: @Sparky256 They already are. "Each Prius uses 2.2 pounds of neodymium in its electric motor magnets"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ferrite has a low reluctance (basically the magnetic equivalent of resistance) which means that magnetic fields flow real easily through it. I don't know the magnetic permeability of Neodymium offhand (permeability is 1/reluctance, the magnetic equivalent of conductance) but if it's some small value (as JonRB suggested), then it'd act as if it wasn't there (high reluctance = high resistance = open circuit) and would offer no benefit over an air core. Ferrite also has the nice advantage of low hysteresis losses, hysteresis loss is the energy wasted in magnetising and demagnetising the core as the voltage/current in the coils change, NdFeB magnets magnetise *real* well (and like to *stay* magnetised, they have *real good* magnetic hysteresis) so that's a fail right there. There's also the slight problem of Neodymium being somewhat rarer (i.e. expensive) than the zinc/manganese/iron/nickle/cobalt ceramic composites used in making most ferrites.